# https not working with www and DNS redirect isn't helping

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, ssl, configuration, https

Not sure why this site is killing me as I've configured SSL on domains before without a problem - but the combination of DNS management and server configuration is hurting my head - so I'm asking for help.

https://joyasolutions.com is the site.

It works in these configurations:

http://joyasolutions.com
https://joyasolutions.com
http://www.joyasolutions.com

It does not work for https://www.joyasolutions.com

Here is what the config looks like:

[image]

[image]

I have had it configured in other ways - but recently updated the cert and installed the intermmediate cert and it seems to be working great except for the redirect which gives an error for https with the subdomain.

I have tried a cname record configuration and that did not work - but if you want to suggest a specific solution on DNS Made Easy - with cname - let me know. Appreciate any ideas and suggestions. Obviously I need all 4 options working. I'm happy to do configuration in IIS to push to HTTPS always as well - but am not certain exactly what to do about that one.

OK... per help from -Brennan Smith I have changed to cname and have implemented an inbound rule that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Is it a typo ? (https://www.joyasolutions.) As of course a domain name without the TLD can't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see, it appears that you are using two separate SSL certs for www and the root domain.

For the root domain (which works) it's a GeoTrust SSL cert with the following SHA1 fingerprint: DF EC DC 43 0F A3 0F 1B 86 72 D2 4E 87 81 D7 5F F4 70 C8 29

For the www domain (which fails) it's a Self Signed cert with the SHA1 fingerprint of: A4 44 C5 FE 95 45 82 68 7E C0 33 2C 12 B6 11 F7 12 04 D4 A8

It also appears that www and root are to two separate endpoints and www is a redirection node for DNS Made Easy. Since DNS Made Easy doesn't have your SSL cert on their redirector servers, the domain doesn't match.

A very simple fix would be setting www to be a CNAME of the root domain, and let your servers at the core handle the redirect.

On a totally unrelated, but important note - you should make sure that all of the permutations redirect to one single domain for SEO purposes. Getting slammed by Google/Bing for duplicate content is common in this case.

Comment: Ok, so I just removed the redirect record on DNS made easy, and I added a cname record for www to root. Was there anything else you were suggesting I do? I've previously only ever used DNS from registrars where I've also purchased certs - so that make some sense why this is different.

Comment: It looks like you need to setup your IIS server to accept requests from www and return a 301 redirect to the root. But HTTPS is working now! :)

Comment: Ok - not sure exactly how to do that in IIS but I'll go attack it.

Comment: There's a good explanation at the URL here starting at step 9: http://hamletbatista.com/seo-geek-school/redirect-www-non-www-iis/

Comment: That was very useful - thanks. Should it take a while for that to take effect? I put an image of what I created in IIS into the detail above... but I'm still getting 500 errors on the www version without https.

Comment: https://www.joyasolutions.com is correctly returning a 301 to http://joyasolutions.com on my end without any SSL errors. 

DNS does take some time to propagate, but given that you are getting 500 errors, it sounds like it has resolved on your end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41584/discussion-between-brennen-smith-and-mary-camacho).